# How to compute the Jacobson radical for a matrix ring over $ p$-adic fields?

Tags: ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I met a problem in dealing with representations of $p$-adic groups. The problem is to compute the Jacobson radical of such a matrix ring:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\mathcal{O}_F & \mathcal{O}_F\\
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathcal{O}_F
\end{array}\right)
$$
where the notations are used in the usual sense: $F$ is a non-archimedean local field, $\mathcal{O}_F$ its ring of integers, and $\mathfrak{P}_F$ the maximal ideal.

I know the example of the full matrix ring: if $R$ is a ring with Jacobson radical $\mathfrak{J}$, then the Jacobson radical of the full matrix ring $M_n(R)$ is exactly $M_n(\mathfrak{J})$. (I learnt this example from Lam's famous GTM text, A First Course on Noncommutative Rings.) But I have no idea how to deal with the above "variation". (I have no experience in dealing with hereditary orders or maximal orders of simple algebras over local fields: maybe I should learn the monograph Maximal Orders by Reiner? )

Any hint or help would be welcome. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. While researching it I ran across [Sands, A. D. "Radicals and Morita contexts." Journal of Algebra 24.2 (1973): 335-345.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869373901439/pdf?md5=a8626d113f77b09454327119065d881a&pid=1-s2.0-0021869373901439-main.pdf&_valck=1) which has the following nice theorem:

[image]

Viewing your ring as a Morita context ring $(R, V, W, S)=(\mathcal O_F, \mathcal O_F, \mathfrak P_F, \mathcal O_F)$.

Elsewhere in the paper they do confirm that the Jacobson radical is an $N$-radical, and rewriting this in terms of your rings it'd be

$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathfrak P_F & \mathcal O_F\\ \mathfrak P_F& \mathfrak P_F\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Oh my god, ring theory is so deep and beautiful. I hope I could understand what is a Morita context ring in the future :) ( I found it in Lam’s second course, section 18. It seems very hard for me as a non-professional.)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite as general as rschwieb's answer, but here's how I would have done it:
The units of the ring $$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\mathcal{O}_F & \mathcal{O}_F\\
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathcal{O}_F
\end{array}\right)
$$
are exactly the elements of
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\mathcal{O}_F^\times & \mathcal{O}_F\\
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathcal{O}_F^\times
\end{array}\right)
$$ (hint: determinant, and formula for inverse of $2 \times 2$-matrices).

Now remember one of the characterisations of the Jacobson radical of a unital ring $R$ is that it consists of all $x$ such $1+RxR \subseteq R^\times$. It is rather clear from this that the two-sided ideal

$$
I :=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathcal{O}_F\\
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathfrak{P}_F
\end{array}\right)
$$

is contained in $Jac(R)$. To see the converse inclusion $Jac(R) \subseteq I$, consider $R/I$.

---

Another way to get there: If one sees $p$-adic matrix rings like that, it is always a good idea to consider their quotient "mod $p$", or here, modulo the ideal

$$
Q :=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathfrak{P}_F\\
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathfrak{P}_F
\end{array}\right).
$$

You get $R/Q \simeq 
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
k_F & k_F\\
0& k_F
\end{array}\right)$, the upper triangular matrices with entries from the residue field $k_F$. This quotient has Jacobson radical $Jac(R/Q)=
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0& k_F\\
0&0
\end{array}\right)$, so one hopes one gets $Jac(R)$ by lifting this. (That's not a full proof, but an extra idea how to come up with the "candidate" $$
I :=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathcal{O}_F\\
\mathfrak{P}_F & \mathfrak{P}_F
\end{array}\right) ).
$$

Comment: Oh thanks! Such an elementary and handy solution is just what I need! :)

Comment: I wanted to use the quasiregularity characterization on that ideal too, but at first I didn't see how it worked. One needs to show $\begin{bmatrix}1+i & r\\j&1+k\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible, i.e. the determinant $(1+i)(1+k)-rj$ is a unit in $\mathcal O_F$. But then it hit me that if this were to be a nonunit (in $\mathfrak P_F$) that would mean the unit $(1+i)(1+k)$ would be there too (an obvious contradiction.). So, it was easier than I initially thought.